# Usage of hyphen when naming colors

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation, colors

When is it appropriate to use a hyphen when naming colors?

For instance `Blue-green` has a dash but `Teal blue` does not.

Is there some general English rule that applies?

Comment: In general compound words are very flexible in how they're spelt, whether that's with a space, a hyphen or nothing at all. I wouldn't worry about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally one uses a hyphen for compound adjectives where they precede the noun or noun clause which they describe.

For example, I would write 'A blue-green sea provided the background curtain to the open-air theatre'.

But I might equally say 'My favourite colour is blue green', and 'I love being in the open air'.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Your second example seems to use "open" to modify "air."  If you really want to treat "open air" as a noun, then I'd prefer to see it hyphenated.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Of course I am using 'open' to modify 'air'. In the second example 'air' is a noun. Would you have it that every time you use an adjective to qualify a noun that you hyphenate them? 'The suspect is a tall-man, with large-feet, a grey-beard, and blue-eyes'!

Comment: Yes, but in your second example, I still think "blue-green" is preferable because it's a single color, not a modified color.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My old granny used to say 'Blue and green should never be seen, Unless there's something in-between'. So perhaps your idea of a hyphen is right. Personally I find it easier to say 'turquoise'.

Answer (score 1):

In ***blue-green*** there two distinct colors, so it's really a combination of blue and green, i.e., a bluish green. It's a **compound adjective** as in *blue-green algae*; can also be used as a noun for that shade of color.  --> use hyphen.

In *teal blue* 'teal' is a particular shade of "moderate or dark bluish green to greenish blue", so it merely provides additional information on what kind of (shade of) blue, in the expression *teal blue*. *Teal* is the adjective and *blue* is the noun.  --> no hyphen.

Comment: But what if it's a "teal-blue teacup" ? :-) . So you see it does depend on the full construction.  (Yes I know I went off-topic, since my example is not naming a color but rather naming the color of an object)

Comment: @Carl It still works: 'teal blue teacup' not 'teal-blue teacup', like 'light blue', not 'light-blue'.

Comment: You certain?  "teal" modifies "blue," not "teacup."

Comment: @Carl: I think in that example, the color is still "teal blue," but since it's an adjective phrase preceding a noun, it becomes hyphenated.